# Neo4j Community Windows JMX monitoring

Tags: neo4j, jmx

Is it an out-of-box function for community version?
I cannot connect to neo4j-jmx using JConsole.
I tried to follow this link: http://neo4j.com/docs/snapshot/jmx-remote.html
But I couldn't find conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf.
Is it only for Enterprise edition?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you open the service dashboard app there's a settings button where you can edit the config files. If you can't find what you need there, you can download the zip instead of the installer, and that should have a full conf folder.